# Comparison operators in amp-bind

Tags: amp-html

I am trying implement macro in amp as follows:

```
<amp-bind-macro id="isTest" arguments="str" expression="str==='test'" />
```

But this error is thrown:

```
amp-bind-macro#isTest.i-amphtml-element.i-amphtml-layout-container.i-amphtml-error %s amp- 
bind: Parsing amp-bind-macro failed. Parse error on line 1:
str==='test'
-----^
Expecting '(', '!', '-', '+', 'NAME', '[', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULL', 
'{', got 'INVALID'​​​
```

I am guessing this is because of AMP not supporting the `===` operator. If so how can I perform such a comparison between any two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [amp-bind expression grammar](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#expression-grammar) does list `==` (but not `===`) as supported. Therefore, this works:

```
<amp-bind-macro id="isTest" arguments="str" expression="str=='test'" />
```

While `==` does type coercion as well (e.g. `'10' == 10` is true), this is probably not that big of an issue, since `amp-bind` expressions tend to be simple. If you have a use-case where you feel `===` is required, I suggest you open [an issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) and give this as feedback to the AMP team.